# A question about cubes in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have a cube. Then clearly it has $6$ faces. In particular it has $6$ faces in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If we look at a cube in $\mathbb{R}^4$ it will actually have $8$ faces. One could keep doing this, and get the number of faces for $\mathbb{R}^n$ in general. Based off of the pattern I would take a guess that the number of faces a cube has in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $2 \cdot n$ however this answer bothers me. The reason is that if you just considered a square in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the formula says it has $4$ faces, which it doesnt. This leads me to believe that my formula is wrong, or I am looking at it the wrong way. In general could I get some insight as to what the number of faces a cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$ would have.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A square in $\mathbb R^2$ does have 4 (1-dimensional) faces. Why don't you think it does?

Comment: You are correct in saying that a cube in ${\Bbb R}^4$ has $8$ "faces", but what these faces actually are is three-dimensional cubes.  In the same way, the $6$ faces of a cube in ${\Bbb R}^3$ are two-dimensional, and the "faces" of a cube in ${\Bbb R}^2$ are one-dimensional - in more usual language, the "faces" of a square are its $4$ edges.

Comment: You probably want to use the term "facet" (instead of "face") for an $(n-1)$-dimensional element of an $n$-dimensional cube (or any $n$-dimensional polytope). It'll help with web searches. That aside, your formula is correct. As indicated in the "Elements" section of [the Wikipedia  "Hypercube" entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube#Elements), the number of $m$-dimensional elements of an $n$-cube is $$2^{n-m}\binom{n}{m}$$ For $m=n-1$, this reduces to $2n$.

Comment: Also, I have edited the question title to be more accurate.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

A square has four sides. A cube has six faces. A hypercube has eight whatever-you-want-to-call- them. Etc. In each case, picture the center of the square, cube, hypercube, etc. as coinciding with that of the bidimensional plane, tridimensional space, four-dimensional hyperspace, etc. and that each pair of opposing sides, faces, whatever, are perpendicular on an axis. In $2$D there are two axes, in $3$D, three axes, in $4$D, four axes, etc. And since each of them is perpendicular on a pair of sides or faces, etc. then there are $2n$ such elements in *n*-dimensional space, an extra pair being gained with each new dimension.